# Newly created sidekiq worker not found (NameError: uninitialized constant UniqueJobWorkerTest::UniqueJobWorker)

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

unique_job_worker.rb

```
# -*- encoding : utf-8 -*-
require_relative 'logging_helper'

class UniqueJobWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include WorkerHelper
  sidekiq_options retry: false,
                  backtrace: true,
                  queue: :sender,
                  failures: true

  def perform(worker,campaign_guid, queue)
    require'pry';binding.pry
  end
end
```

unique_job_worker_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'mocha/setup'

class UniqueJobWorkerTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    require'pry';binding.pry
    @worker = UniqueJobWorker.new
  end
  
  test "it exists" do
    assert @worker
  end
end
```

When enqueued through redis I get this response

```
INFO -- : Exception: uninitialized constant UniqueJobWorker
```

Any suggestions as to why my newly created worker, UniqueJobWorker, is not being found during runtime through redis or through a simple test?

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: If you fire up a rails console and just run ``UniqueJobWorker``, what happens?

Comment: Rails is not included on the workers app. Just ruby and sidekiq.

Comment: If you're not using Rails then please provide more detail on how you enqueue the job and how you load your classes.

Comment: In terms of your test file, it doesn't look like you are requiring ``unique_job_worker``. Is that being done somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use sidekiq outside of Rails, you need to use the `-r` option to tell it how to load your workers. So (assuming that your worker is in a sub-directory called `workers`):

```
% sidekiq -r ./workers/unique_job_worker.rb
```

If you have multiple workers, an option is to create a loader file to ensure everything is loaded.

**load_workers.rb**

```rb
($LOAD_PATH << 'workers').uniq!
require 'unique_job_worker'
require 'other_worker'
...
```

Then require the loader file on the command line:

```
% sidekiq -r ./load_workers.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and ended up being a Redis namespace issue:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/2834#issuecomment-184800981

Adding that fixed it for me:

```
config.redis = {
    url: ENV['REDIS_URL'],
    namespace: "some_namespace_different_for_each_app"
}
```

You also need the `redis-namespace` gem BTW